# How do i load structure into array / object / class?

Tags: vb.net

How do I load the below structure into VB.Net array / object / class? and how do I get access to specific element?

I retrieved it from the binance api using this link:

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=30m&limit=2

[
  [
    1571896800000,
    "7412.72000000",
    "7414.38000000",
    "7361.01000000",
    "7376.28000000",
    "964.39453100",
    1571898599999,
    "7124637.09263142"
    ,8360,
    "491.13171700",
    "3627861.01587878",
    "0"
   ],
   [
    1571898600000,
    "7376.39000000",
    "7395.06000000",
    "7337.99000000",
    "7370.76000000",
    "926.16601400",
    1571900399999,
    "6820821.48483493",
    7666,
    "449.47121800",
    "3311765.73197726",
    "0"
   ]
]

i know how to parse string, i wonder if there is better / easier way.

This is how i retrieve the data from the API:

```
Function APICall2(ByVal Security As String, ByVal command As String, Optional ByVal param1 As String = "", Optional ByVal param2 As String = "", Optional ByVal param3 As String = "")
    Dim APIUrl As String
    APIUrl = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/" + command + "?symbol=" + Security + "&interval=" + param1 + "&limit=1"
    Dim Request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(APIUrl), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Dim Response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(Request.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
    Dim Read = New System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd
    APICall2 = Read

End Function
```

Comment: That's a JSON. Install [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (from Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution). You can find a host of code samples related to deserializing/serializing a JSON:

Comment: As a suggestion, that JSON can be deseriaized to a `List(Of List(Of Double))` or `List(Of List(Of String))` (the latter if you want to keep the zeros).

Comment: Can someone show me a code sample please ? I'm new to vb.net and feel clueless...

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggested, install Newtonsoft.Json.Net to assist with parsing the json data. Then, it's as simple as

```vb
'Array option
Dim stringArray= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of String())(yourJsonString)

'List option
Dim listOfStrings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(yourJsonString)
```

This essentially parses json "structure" and loads it into your desired collection type.